# While passing a sting from one code to other I am facing errors?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Code 1

```
public class Program {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      char[] aa = new char[] {'a','b'};
      possibleStrings(3, aa,"");
      char[] bb = new char[] {'|','&'};
      possibleStrings(2, bb,"");
      result(aa,bb);   }
```

Code 2

```
    public static void possibleStrings(int maxLength, char[] alphabet, String curr) 
{  //THIS CODE IS COMMON FOR STRING aa and bb.}
```

Code 3

```
  public static void result(char[] a,char[] b) {
//APPENDING BOTH THE STRING CHARACTER BY CHARACTER
        char[] arrayA = a.toCharArray();
        char[] arrayB = b.toCharArray();    
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        while( i < arrayA.length && i < arrayB.length){
        sb.append(arrayA[i]).append(arrayB[i]);
        ++i;
        }
        for(int j = i; j < arrayA.length; ++j){
            sb.append(arrayA[j]);
        }
        for(int j = i; j < arrayB.length; ++j){
            sb.append(arrayB[j]);
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString()); 
  }           
}
```

I am trying to pass character string aa and bb from code 1 to code 3. But I am facing error.
Its showing something like this:

> ```
> Program.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
>         char[] arrayA = a.toCharArray();
>                          ^
>   symbol:   method toCharArray()
>   location: variable a of type char[]
> Program.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
>         char[] arrayB = b.toCharArray();    
>                          ^
>   symbol:   method toCharArray()
>   location: variable b of type char[]
> 2 errors
> ```

I am not getting where I am going wrong. Please help me out.

Comment: `a.toCharArray()` `a` as well as `b` are already `char arrays` therefore that method doesnt exist for them

Comment: ^^ *"While passing a sting from one code to other I am facing errors?"* `char[]` != `String`

Comment: meaning, this has nothing to do with passing String-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function :

```
 public static void result(char[] a,char[] b) {
//APPENDING BOTH THE STRING CHARACTER BY CHARACTER
        char[] arrayA = a.toCharArray();
        char[] arrayB = b.toCharArray();    
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        while( i < arrayA.length && i < arrayB.length){
        sb.append(arrayA[i]).append(arrayB[i]);
        ++i;
        }
        for(int j = i; j < arrayA.length; ++j){
            sb.append(arrayA[j]);
        }
        for(int j = i; j < arrayB.length; ++j){
            sb.append(arrayB[j]);
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString()); 
  }           
}
```

You are already passing char arrays as arguements. So you in line `char[] arrayA = a.toCharArray();` you are trying to convert a char array to char array. And that method does not exist.

Comment: Wrong. Converting a char array to a char array doesn't pose the problem. The actual problem is that the method `toCharArray()` doesn't even exist for char arrays

Comment: also: the method toCharArray() of String doesn't convert anything. It returns a char Array based on the String, but the String itself remains unchanged.